# DataTable Rowfilter syntax for rows where a column is null or empty

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datatable

So I tried to filter some rows out if a column is empty or null.
How do I do that?

It looks like I need some sort of SQL-Like statement.
I want something like:

```
t.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("[disabilities] IS NOT NULL OR EMPTY");
```

Comment: What have you tried? What were the results?

Comment: @RyanWilson haven't try empty yet cos I dont know the syntax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As equivalent to `String.IsNullOrEmpty` in data table filter expression, you can use either of the following options:

- `dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "ISNULL(ColumnName,'')=''"`
- `dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "LEN(ISNULL(ColumnName,''))=0"`
- `dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "ColumnName IS NULL OR ColumnName=''"`

To make it `!String.IsNullOrEmpty`, you can use `NOT(criteria)` or use not equal operator `<>`:

- `dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "NOT(ISNULL(ColumnName,'')='')"`
- `dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "NOT(LEN(ISNULL(ColumnName,''))=0)"`
- `dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "NOT(ColumnName IS NULL OR ColumnName='')"`

For more information about filter expression syntax, take a look at  [`DataColumn.Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.7.2).